# Which file-sharing websites provide direct links to uploaded files?

Tags: file-sharing

I wonder if there are some websites that provide direct links to files that have been uploaded?

By "direct links", I mean I can get links to the files on one machine, and the links are still good to use on another machine.

For example, I used to use `http://ifile.it` which did provide direct links after "request download link", but it has changed to `http://filecloud.io`, the links I get after request downloadlink cannot be used on a different machine.

Comment: [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com)?

Comment: @Bibhas: Dropbox seems not to provide the direct link that can be used on another computer.

Comment: There is option to generate public url in Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox does. Right click the file and click `Copy public URL` and you can then paste the direct URL for that file.

Comment: The Public folder feature has been transformed; any file can be shared by generating it’s public link. See [this](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en) help page for details.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Updated the answer. Thanks for mentioning :)